# If statement in Javascript return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am learning Javascript. I wrote a JS to return a Json-type value.

```
  var generateUrl = function(Name, Letter, rootUrl, V1) {
  rootUrl = rootUrl || Letter;
  return  {
    classname: 'mycss-' + Letter,
    text: Name,
    url: rootHref.replace(Rex, "$1" + rootUrl + "."),
    onclick: {
      fn: clickFn,
      obj: V1
    }
  };
};
```

I want to add a `if statement` inside `url:`. 
For example, if `Name = google`, `url` won't use this logic `rootHref.replace(Rex, "$1" + rootUrl + ".")`, instead it will directly `return an url`.
I have searched for an answer quite a while but still have no luck. May someone tell me how to add a `if statement` logic in my code.

Comment: Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead.

Comment: That thing you're returning is called an object literal, nothing to do with JSON.  You can't put much logic into an object literal, but you can assign it to a variable and then use bracket or dot notation to assign a new property value (eg `if (thing == "google") myObj.url = "google-specific URL";`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as follows

```
 url: (num == 1) ? Link1 : Link2,
```